# Grails g:uploadForm redirect

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a g:uploadForm that appears inside a modal dialog.
After I submit a g:uploadForm, it starts to upload my file but then after that's done it tries to go to an upload.jsp and doesn't find it. What I want instead is for the modal dialog not to close once the file has finished uploading. How can I go about supressing the closing of the modal on which the form appears. I think the real question is how can I supress the browser looking for an upload.jsp once the file is uploaded. Instead I want it to stay on the modal that was used to browse and then upload the file.

Here is the upload form:

```
<g:uploadForm class = "uploaderForm" action="upload">
                    <div id = "fileType">
                        <p><u>File Type</u></p>
                        <label for="excelFile">Excel:</label><g:radio id = "excelFile" name="fileTypegrp" value="1" checked="true"/><br>
                        <label for="textFile">Text File(delimited):</label><g:radio id = "textFile" name="fileTypegrp" value="2" disabled="true"/><br>
                        <label for="xmlFile">XML:</label><g:radio id = "xmlfile" name="fileTypegrp" value="3" disabled="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "dataType">
                        <p><u>Data Type</u></p>
                        <label for="accData">Account Data:</label><g:radio id = "accData" name="dataTypegrp" value="1"/><br>
                        <label for="entData">Entity Data:</label><g:radio id = "entData" name="dataTypegrp" value="2"/><br>
                        <label for="indData">Individual Data:</label><g:radio id = "indData" name="dataTypegrp" value="3"/><br>
                    </div>  
                    <div id = "uploaderfield">
                        <input id = "chseFile" type="file" name="file"/><br>
                        <button id = "submFile" type="button">Upload</button>
                        <button id = "cancel1" class = "close" type="button"> Cancel </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id ="uploadErrors"><div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label" style ="color: black;">Loading...</div></div></div>
                </g:uploadForm>
```

and here is the javascript for the button that submits it:

```
$("#submFile").click(function () {
    if ($("#chseFile").val() == "") {
        $("#uploadErrors").html("<span class='text'>You must select a file to upload.</span>");
        $("#uploadErrors").show();
        $("#uploadErrors .text").fadeOut(3000);
        }
    else if (getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('dataTypegrp')) == "") {
        $("#uploadErrors").html("<span class='text'>You must select a data type to upload.</span>");
        $("#uploadErrors").show();
        $("#uploadErrors .text").fadeOut(3000);
    }
    else {
        $("#progressbar").show();
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: false,
            change: function() {
                $(".progress-label").text( $("#uploadErrors").progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
            },
            complete: function() {
                $(".progress-label").text( "Complete!" );
            }
        });
        $(".uploaderForm").submit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this using the `g:uploadForm` in a modal you will need to implement posting the form to an `iframe`.

This is pretty simple. Just add an `iframe` to your modal/page and then set the `target` on your `form` to match the name of the `iframe`. For example:

```
<g:uploadForm name="someForm" 
    controller="myController" 
    action="saveUpload 
    class="form-horizontal" 
    role="form" 
    target="hidden-upload-frame">
...
</g:uploadForm>
...
<iframe id="hidden-upload-frame" 
    name="hidden-upload-frame" 
    style="display: none;">
</iframe>
```

If you need the page/modal to react to the file being uploaded then the `controller` can render that to the `iframe` (e.g. javascript/jquery).

Comment: Ok I will try this. Can I assume safely from your skeleton code above that Grails' GSP tags like g:uploadForm for example, inherit the attributes of the base HTML tags they are built upon? Also, what does the role attribute do? I didn't find it listed on W3 when exploring the <form> tag.

Comment: That is a safe assumption. What it actually does, if the attribute isn't known as an attribute of the GSP tag itself it simply echos the attribute and value. The role attribute is an HTML5 attribute for the form (seen in this example because I was thinking of it within a bootstrap modal).

Comment: Further information about the role attribute can be found here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/PF/XTech/HTML5/RoleAttribute